# Run-time error 13: Type Mismatch in VBA when trying to call function from another workbook

Tags: function, vba

So the following code I had worked when the Function was in the same Workbook as my Sub:

```
 FDError= FilterData(sh, current)
```

But now its been moved to another workbook and I have to call it from there I'm getting an error (Run-time error 13: Type Mismatch):

```
FDError = Application.Run("'" & rwb.Name & "'!FilterData", "sh", "current")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the help to `Application.Run`: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa220716(v=office.11).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa220716%28v=office.11%29.aspx)

The problem is that you didn't provided the actual arguments required by the macro in order to run, but rather their names as strings. You'd want to call:

```
FDError = Application.Run("'" & rwb.Name & "'!FilterData", sh, current)
```

where `sh` and `data` should be two variables that have the correct type (i.e. they are, or can be converted to, `Variant`), and are properly initialized.